# Web Inspector not finding BlackBerry 10 Simulator WebWorks App

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-10, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-webworks, web-inspector

I access web inspector through `http://simulatorIPaddress:1337/` in chrome on the desktop and I can inspect any pages of the Browser on my simulator. I've built the WebWorks app with the bbwp command with -d flag added. When I start the app the pop-up with Web Inspector Enabled appears. Development Mode is turned on, Web Inspector is turned on. However, only the browser appears in the Web Inspector list. Can anyone help on this? Should the developer mode IP matter? Should the pop-up show an IP address? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every web inspector session is on its own port. So if the browser is already using 1337, your session is likely on port 1338.